# Use angular-translate to set placeholder value onblur

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I am new to Angular.
Implementing localization in the project. I've got many inputs and I must translate placeholders. In HTML I have something like this

```
<input  type="email" placeholder="{{ 'TRANSLATION_KEY' | translate }}" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='{{ 'TRANSLATION_KEY' | translate }}'" required>
```

But this part of the code doesn't work:(

```
onblur="this.placeholder='{{ 'TRANSLATION_KEY' | translate }}'"
```

How to set translated value to placeholder onblur?
I'll appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good approach to the problem [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/keszkkLa/):

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input  type="email" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" ng-focus="setPlaceholder()" ng-blur="setPlaceholder('TRANSLATION_KEY')" required>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.placeholder = $filter('translate')('TRANSLATION_KEY');

    $scope.setPlaceholder = function (data) {
        $scope.placeholder = $filter('translate')(data);
    };
})
.filter('translate', function () {
    return function (data) {
        return data;
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: You are welcome, if my answer solved your problem please consider to accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I have another solution. More universal and easy. Just add this line to your input in the view

```
onfocus="this.ph=this.placeholder;this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder=this.ph"
```